# Internet category not returning any results in Synapse

Tags: 10.10, zeitgeist, synapse

I recently installed [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) and I noticed there is an `Internet` category on the far right, but there it doesn't return any results. What do I need to do to enable it to search my web browsing history? I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Google Chrome, you must install the Zeitgeist Extension.

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/zeitgeist-extension-for-chrome-to-use.html

Comment: anything like this for firefox?

Comment: Firefox one also exists. Getting it up and running for an end-user is still a bit of trouble. I have been trying to understand how to package it but is still confusing for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me on 11.10, the answer on webupd8 doesn't work, recent comment there also mentions such a problem. Looks like for now you'll need to download and build plug-ins manually.

Instructions are [here](http://wiki.zeitgeist-project.com/Installing_Zeitgeist_Data-Sources_from_trunk). I tried to find a work around for a few hours and found none, will update if it worked.